# Finding a PDF given the MGF

Tags: probability, statistics

If I am given a MGF of any probability density function, say $\dfrac{1}{1-t}$ How can I find the PDF? What would the idea be behind this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MGF is actually Laplace transformation of PDF, namely $M_X(t)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{tX}f(x)dx$. To restore PDF, just inverse the transformation. But this is not always easy.

In your example, inverse Laplace transformation of $\frac1{1-t}$ is $e^{-x}$, which is exponential distribution with parameter 1.

Comment: It should also be noted that this is not always possible, but subject to some limitations. When these criteria are not met, there may be multiple PDFs with the same MGF.

Comment: in what case would that be? example?

Answer (score 0):

Inverse Laplace transform or you can simply recognise it as the mgf of an exponential(1) distribution.